# Creating applet in java

Tags: swing, jinternalframe

What is the error in `dt.add(tf)` statement?

```
/*<applet code="applicant" height=300 width=300></applet>*/
import javax.swing.*;
public class applicant extends JApplet
{
  static JPanel panel;
  JLabel labelAppID;
  JLabel labelAppName;
  JLabel labelAppAddress;
  JLabel labelAppPosition;
  JTextField textAppID;
  JTextField textAppName;
  JTextField textAppAddress;
  JComboBox comboAppPosition;
  public void init()
  {
    panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    labelAppID=new JLabel("Applicant ID");
    labelAppName=new JLabel("Name");
    labelAppAddress=new JLabel("Address");
    labelAppPosition=new JLabel("Position");
    textAppID=new JTextField(5);
    textAppName=new JTextField(30);
    textAppAddress=new JTextField(30);
    String positions[]={"Manager", "Executive", "Associate"};
    comboAppPosition=new JComboBox(positions);
    panel.add(labelAppID);
    panel.add(textAppID);
    panel.add(labelAppName);
    panel.add(textAppName);
    panel.add(labelAppAddress);
    panel.add(textAppAddress);
    panel.add(labelAppPosition);
    panel.add(comboAppPosition);
       setTitle("JToolBar as a Tool Palette - Example");
      JPanel jp=(JPanel)getContentPane();
      jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      JDesktopPane dt=new JDesktopPane();
      dt.setBackground(jp.getBackground());
      jp.add("center",dt);
      JFrame tf=new JFrame("Tools");
      dt.add(tf);
    }    
 }
```

Comment: what is the error in dt.add statement

Comment: In future, please copy/paste the exact compile or run-time error message.  Those messages give a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

A [JInternalFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) can be added to a JDesktopPane, whereas a JFrame cannot.

See [How to Use Internal Frames](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) in the Java Tutorial for further details.